# Why do I get the error 'not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin' after I use setRequestHeader?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

After searching for a while, I cannot find the answer yet. 
My problem is when I call a web service function setRequestHeader, I got the error "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

Here is my javaScript code:

```
var loginController = new sap.ltst.login.loginController({controllerName: "sap.ltst.login.loginController"});
var session = loginController.login("I051486", "123456789");
var config = {};
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authentication', 'Authentication-Token ' + session.session_token);
    },
    url : "http://localhost:8081/com.sap.st.gtpapi/program/"
            + this.program + "/configs",
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'GET',
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
        config = data;
    }
});
return config;
```

In web service side, I have a function that I can enable or disable the authentication. I tried to set the auth as false (not check the auth) then remove setRequestHeader, I got no error and the web service returns me some data.

In another way I tried to put it back, I got the error.

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/gtpapi/program/Business%20Intelligence%20platform%204.1%20(BI%20Aurora%204.1)/configs. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So I don't think that it's the problem of the auth because in the web service side, I disable the auth verification.

Let's move to the web service side, this is the interface:

```
    public static final String HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN = "Authentication-Token";
    @GET
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/guid_{planId}/packages/{packId}/{results}")
    public Response setPackageResult(@PathParam("planId") final String planGuid,    @PathParam("packId") final String packGuid, @PathParam("results") final String results, @HeaderParam(WebServiceBase.HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN) String token);
```

This is the header response et request on Chrome:

```
Request       URL:http://localhost:8081/com.sap.st.gtpapi/program/SBOP%20EXPLORER%204.1/configs
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authentication, origin
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8081
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/LTST_Frontend/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Response Headersview source
Allow:GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/xml
Date:Fri, 02 Aug 2013 15:44:10 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I'm not sure I did some mistake whether the problem comes from javaScript or web service. Any ideas?

Comment: Different port is different origin

Comment: @Esailija But why don't I get the error when I don't use the setRequestHeader?

Comment: Could be that 8081 is responding with CORS headers but doesn't allow credentials. Otherwise seems security bug.. see here that different port is different origin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules

Comment: Try adding `crossDomain: true` into your `$.ajax` function

Comment: @PRPGFerret Already tried that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put any header you want to send in the safe list:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authentication, X-Custom-Header, .. etc");
```

This should be part of the `CORS` headers on the **receiving** domain.

Comment: Could you please explain me some more details? I'm not sure where should I put this, on the web service or client side.

Comment: In the webservice, where your other `CORS` headers are.

Comment: This is what I've tried but it doesn't work.
public static Response sendResponse(String content){
  ResponseBuilder response = ok(content);
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authentication, origin, content-type, accept");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  return response.build();
 }